# R: Subtract group/class mean from each observation

Tags: r

I have a dataframe X with

1. a column of counts (Counts)
2. a column of class labels (Labels)

I have calculated a separate dataframe Y that has

1. A column of class labels (Labels)
2. A column of class count means

I would like to create a new vector that Z by iterating through each row of X and subtracting the class mean for the appropriate class from each observed count.

Z = [X$count_1 - Y$mean_k, ... , X$count_n - Y$mean_k]

I would like to do so using base R and no other packages.

I know that I could do this using a for loop that checks that the label of the observed count in X matches the label of the class mean in Y, but that seems inefficient. How can I vectorize this operation?

Edit:

I figured it out. This got me what I wanted:

apply(SandwichAnts, 1, function(x) as.numeric(x["Ants"]) - (mean_fillings[mean_fillings$Filling == x["Filling"],][,2]))

Comment: Simply merge on labels and then create a new column (i.e., vector) of count and mean difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# generate X and Y
X <- data.frame(counts = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
            labels = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'))
Y <- aggregate(X$counts, by=list(X$labels),  
           FUN=mean)
colnames(Y) <- c('label', 'avg')
Y
#  label avg
#1     a 1.5
#2     b 3.5

# use the labels as row names for Y
rownames(Y) <- Y$label
D <- X$counts - Y[X$labels, 'avg']
D
# [1] -0.5  0.5 -0.5  0.5
```